# Codeception failing tests take too long to run

Tags: unit-testing, codeception

I have just added Codeception to some of my projects but its performance is unacceptable for failing tests. Passing tests execute in 0.1s or less but failing tests take between 15 minutes and 1.5 hours *each*. When they finally fail, they dump hundreds of kilobytes to the console. There is a lot of mention of Selenium, which I don't understand because so far I'm only using unit tests, not acceptance tests or functional tests so I don't see why it should need Selenium. Why is it so slow? Is there something I can configure to make a failing test run as fast as a passing test? These are the tests I'm using:

```
<?php

class englishTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit {
  /**
   * @var \UnitTester
   */
  protected $tester;

  protected function _before() {
    include_once('country.model.php');
  }

  protected function _after() {
  }

  // tests
  public function testCreateCountryModel() {
    $country = new CountryModel;
    $this->assertEquals('Afghanistan', $country->get_all_countries()[0]);
  }

  public function testGetCountriesEndingWithEndOfWord() {
    $country = new CountryModel;
    $this->assertEquals(['Costa Rica', 'Dominica', 'Jamaica', 'South Africa'], $country->get_countries_ending_with('ca'));
  }

}
```

This is the output when the tests pass:

```
C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\localhost\public_html\english>codecept run
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.2.1
Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Acceptance Tests (0) ---------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------

Functional Tests (0) ---------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------

Unit Tests (2) ---------------------------------------------
+ englishTest: Create country model (0.1s)
+ englishTest: Get countries ending with end of word
------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 2.23 seconds, Memory: 11.00MB

OK (2 tests, 2 assertions)
```

---

#### EDIT

I created a blank directory:

```
C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\localhost\public_html>md deception
```

I bootstrapped Codeception:

```
C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\localhost\public_html>codecept bootstrap deception
 Initializing Codeception in C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\localhost\public_html\deception

File codeception.yml created       <- global configuration
tests/unit created                 <- unit tests
tests/unit.suite.yml written       <- unit tests suite configuration
tests/functional created           <- functional tests
tests/functional.suite.yml written <- functional tests suite configuration
tests/acceptance created           <- acceptance tests
tests/acceptance.suite.yml written <- acceptance tests suite configuration
 ---
tests/_bootstrap.php written <- global bootstrap file
Building initial Tester classes
Building Actor classes for suites: acceptance, functional, unit
 -> AcceptanceTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\AcceptanceTester includes modules: PhpBrowser, \Helper\Acceptance
AcceptanceTester.php created.
 -> FunctionalTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\FunctionalTester includes modules: \Helper\Functional
FunctionalTester.php created.
 -> UnitTesterActions.php generated successfully. 0 methods added
\UnitTester includes modules: Asserts, \Helper\Unit
UnitTester.php created.

Bootstrap is done. Check out C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\localhost\public_html\deception/tests directory
```

I then changed to the directory and ran the following command in it:

```
C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\localhost\public_html\deception>codecept generate:test unit Deception
Test was created in C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\localhost\public_html\deception\tests\unit\DeceptionTest.php
```

I then added a single line to DeceptionTest.php (`$this->assertTrue(false);`):

```
<?php


class DeceptionTest extends \Codeception\Test\Unit
{
  /**
   * @var \UnitTester
   */
  protected $tester;

  protected function _before()
  {
  }

  protected function _after()
  {
  }

  // tests
  public function testMe()
  {
    $this->assertTrue(false);
  }
}
```

Finally, I ran the following:

```
C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\localhost\public_html\deception>codecept run
Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.2.1
Powered by PHPUnit 4.8.26 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Acceptance Tests (0) ---------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------

Functional Tests (0) ---------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------

Unit Tests (1) ---------------------------------------------
x DeceptionTest: Me
------------------------------------------------------------


Time: 3.36 minutes, Memory: 103.25MB

There was 1 failure:

---------
1) DeceptionTest: Me
 Test  tests\unit\DeceptionTest.php:testMe
Failed asserting that false is true.
#1  C:\server\Apache24\htdocs\localhost\public_html\deception\tests\unit\DeceptionTest.php:22
#2  DeceptionTest->testMe
#3  C:\usr\bin\codecept.phar:7

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

As you can see, it took **3.36 minutes** and **103.25MB** to work out that `true !== false`.

Comment: I am almost 100% certain that it is a fault of your code and not of Codeception, please add the failing test, unit.suite.yml, country.model.php and all dependencies if it has any. Also it would be good to know what information is dumped to console.

Comment: If it were a fault of Codeception, $this->assertTrue(false); would take 15 minutes too, right?

Comment: @Naktibalda Excellent suggestion! And yes, `$this->assertTrue(false);` takes forever too. I'll let you know when it finishes.

Comment: How did you create a blank directory?

Comment: I think that the best way to investigate this issue is to profile it with xdebug.

Comment: @Naktibalda xdebug (via QCacheGrind) shows that `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->onNotSuccessfulTest` took 68.66%, `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest` took 14.50% and `PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint->fail` took 15.08% of the time (98.24% of the total). Every other function took less than 0.20%, including `DeceptionTest->testMe` which took 0.00%.

Comment: Did it take 15 minutes this time? If handling of failed result took 15 minutes, it would appear as 99.9% in qcachegrind.

Comment: @Naktibalda I ran it three times and it took 3-4 minutes each time to fail asserting that false is true. One example is above. I can't use or recommend a product that is so slow.

Comment: It isn't a fault of Codeception, I can show you examples where it failed fast on Windows. https://ci.appveyor.com/project/DavertMik/codeception/build/1.0.2244

Comment: PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->onNotSuccessfulTest just throws an exception, please dig deeper and find what it is doing.

Comment: @Naktibalda Are you seriously suggesting that I should debug `throw $e;`? That would mean looking at PHP's C source code, which is obviously going way too far.

Comment: I am saying that you have not provided any useful information.

Comment: Please try again with Codeception 2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use Xdebug with PHP. On a hunch I disabled it and suddenly, Codeception completes all tests, both passing and failing in only a few seconds. The culprit was `xdebug.collect_params = 3` in php.ini. Setting it to any of 0, 1, or 2 fixes the problem.